# how to block my phone from the vps?

Tags: iptables

My android phone wlan mac is x1:x2:x3:x4:x5:X6
I want to block the phone to logon in the vps.
here is the iptable command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source x1:x2:x3:x4:x5:X6 -j DROP
```

I found that it can't block my android phone to logon in the vps.
How to write the iptable rule?

Comment: If your VPS is not on your local network, this will not work. MAC addresses are at the wrong layer to be propagated via the Internet.

Comment: Exactly. Mac address blocks will work only inside Ethernet Scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate by colon such as:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:00:EA:91:04:07 -j DROP
```

NOTE:

MAC addresses contains `0-9` and `A-E`, You have X in your address. It's wrong.